# No minimum question limit on SE sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, quality-filter, triage

I was browsing the Stack Overflow site (specifically the [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) tag (ML)) and I was surprised by how short the questions are becoming in that place. ML is fast growing, but there isn't any moderator to close down or remove posts on that tag. However there is another problem which occurred to me.

I notice that some of the "dumb" or bad questions (which are totally unrelated to their tags) are just too small. Examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61299245/is-it-possible-to-read-thermal-image-from-normal-camera-using-opencv) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61294824/how-to-calculate-the-error-of-a-node-in-backpropagation).

In all these questions, *one* of the problems they all had was that they are too short. So why doesn't SO introduce a minimum character limit for *questions?* It makes sense to have a maximum *and* minimum limit on comments, but I do not see a problem with a minimum text limit on the questions itself too.

If some questions are indeed very small then it would force the OP to at least elaborate. This would produce much better questions that are more helpful and easy to understand.

> Of course, it wouldn't work every time and you may get a whole page of [abusive word removed] but it **would** work on the majority of the questions. So, why doesn't SO implement this feature?

**EDIT==>** I think one of the links has been removed thankfully by a moderator. But it languished for at least 36 hours on the site. I think either we need a dedicated moderator or a minimum text limit....

Comment: Because all this random text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nam no modo sale omnis, propriae pertinax ut per. Ea soleat everti urbanitas est, eos an purto mutat. Legere definitiones sit ut. Eam te rebum iudico constituam would just be added to make up the minimum number of characters.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have mentioned it in my post. But the fact remains - there would always be more benefit from this idea than harm.

Comment: " I think either we need a dedicated moderator" That is the great thing about StackExchange, it is moderated by the users. You can vote a post down, flag it for attention, leave comments etc.. If you earn the rep, you can even delete posts or one vote close them with the right badges or go to a chat room and find others who agree with you, your options are numerous.. So rather than complain about how others aren't doing things as fast as you would like, get out there and get moderating those questions. FYI I strongly disagree short == bad questions.

Comment: @MarkKirby Hey, see my examples. Can you show a question where it is short (and is of this year, not those 11-year-old ones) that have more than 2 votes? Also closing questions require certain badges and rep which most ML people don't have coz it is a newly rising community....

Comment: Here are the top 1000 questions from this year with a score > 2 ordered by their length: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1228869

Comment: "(and is of this year, not those 11-year-old one" Why must it be from this year? That seems to be you stacking the odds because I can find thousands of short questions with100+ votes, anyway here is one https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201991/shell-navigate-up-n-directories for the sake of it. "Also closing questions require certain badges " No anyone can flag or edit a question.

Comment: @rene Well, I can't argue with that. I just thought it intuitively that it would be better and would reduce the bad questions. I think that my method would help remove the tens of thousands of bad questions posted every year. These are only some that are exceptions...

Comment: we already deleted [189027](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1228874) questions this year.

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Triage needs to be fixed urgently, and users need to be notified upon receiving a review ban!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394498/839601)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Overflow has [18 moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) at the moment. None of them are required to close a question or even delete it. That's mostly done by ordinary users who have somewhat more rep than you currently do.

If you think a question is poor then

1. use your downvote on it [once you get 125 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) if you think it's not useful, does not show any research effort or is unclear. You're nearly there on that one.
2. If it can't be answered because it's unclear or too broad or fits any of the other close reasons then flag or vote to close it. Have you flagged these questions for closure yourself? You can already be part of the solution here.

The [first question you link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61299245/is-it-possible-to-read-thermal-image-from-normal-camera-using-opencv) to has been closed and deleted so user moderation is clearly working there.

The other question has 2 of the necessary 3 close votes so I imagine it will be closed fairly soon. Once you get the [cast close and reopen votes privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) you'll be able to see these votes mount up. At the moment it looks to you as if nothing is happening to that question but that's actually not the case.

There are actually question quality checks and we get people complaining most every day that their question could not be submitted because it failed such checks, mostly when they try to just post a dump of their code without explanation.

You can however write a very short but perfectly good question on pretty much any site in any topic so some blanket rule about question length is always going to be insufficiently subtle.

There's also a [chat room dedicated to closing questions](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) so if you read its [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq) and take its [tour](https://socvr.org/tour) perhaps you the people there will help you get questions closed if they are hanging around open too long.

Comment: "At the moment it looks to you as if nothing is happening to that question". Ahh, I never thought about that. Guess the community is not that static than I thought :)